# (gedit:3157): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' does not contain a key named 'enable-delete'

Tags: nautilus, gedit

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Suddenly it gives the error:

```
(gedit:3157): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' does not contain a key named 'enable-delete'
```

when I am trying to open gedit which I use a lot. How can I fix this. This may be something related to nautilus, not sure. Please help.

Comment: You need to look in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml`& see if that key is there, lines 76 - 80. Also try opening nautilus > edit > preferences > behavior & see if that option is there. It should be the 2nd option in the Trash section. If you happened to add & use a gnome3 ppa then please mention that..

Answer (score 1):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/plugins/active-plugins "['spell', 'sort', 'modelines', 'docinfo']"
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264891